# How does Blur Filter work in HTML5 Kinetic.Filters.Blur

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

How I can use blur filter in HTML5?
I find this:

```
Kinetic.Filters.Blur(imageData, config )
```

and Parameters:

```
imageData  {Object}  
config {Object}  
config.radius {Integer}
```

Explain to me with an example that how I can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var image = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 10,
      y: 10,
      image: imageObj,
      filter: Kinetic.Filters.Blur,
      filterRadius: 20
  });
```

Checkout this tutorial: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-tween-blur-filter-with-kineticjs/