# How to apply KineticJS filter ?

Tags: kineticjs

I find the KineticJS filters documentation extremely frustrating and could not find examples online, especially considering brightness.

The kinetic.filters docs [link](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Filters.php) mention a Kinetic.Filters.Brighten(imageData) but there's no info on how to pass parameters to it or how to use it.

All I need is a working example of an image on a layer on a stage, and two buttons - one to make the image brighter and one to make it darker. Can anyone please help me with that ?

Thank you !

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16416952/512042

Comment: sorry but that doesn't help, I need to know the parameters to to the Brighten filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realy, documentation for filters is poor.

Example for Brighten filter: (kineticjs 4.5.0)

```
    darth = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 10,
      y: 10,
      image: imageObj,
      draggable: true,
      filter: Kinetic.Filters.Brighten,
      filterBrightness: -50
    });
```

for animate you can use this tutorial: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-tween-blur-filter-with-kineticjs/

```
    var tween = TweenLite.to(darth, 0.6, {
      paused: true,
      setFilterBrightness: 50,
      onUpdate: function() {
        layer.batchDraw(); 
      }
    });
```

Comment: Ah great thank you ! how would I change the brightness on an existing image though ? do I reapply the filter ? change it's parameters ?

Comment: if image has no filter: "darth.setFilter(Kinetic.Filters.Brighten);" then "darth.setFilterBrightness(-50);"

Comment: Thank you again ! can you please explain the difference between setFilter and applyFilter and when is applyFilter used ?