# extending KineticJS - custom filter

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying do add contrast as a filter to KineticJS (I know, it's not a filter technically). It works, but I want to add `contrast()` modifier too (like `noise()` for Noise filter etc.).

Here is my function (after including KineticJS 5.0.1 library):

```
(function() {

    Kinetic.Filters.Contrast = function(imageData) {
        var data = imageData.data,
            len = data.length,
            i,
            adjust = this.contrast(),
            x = [];

            //[cut] processing, not important here
    };

    Kinetic.Factory.addGetterSetter(Kinetic.Node, 'contrast', 0, null, Kinetic.Factory.afterSetFilter);
})();
```

As you can see, `Kinetic.Factory.addGetterSetter` should provide me `contrast()` modifier, but it doesn't. When I run the code, resuls is `TypeError: imgs.contrast is not a function`:

```
imgs.filters([Kinetic.Filters.Contrast]);
imgs.contrast(30);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**//update**
My temporary solution: just put my function into kineticJS file. Not perfect, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can make out from the [documentation](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Image.html), what you've got should work. However, when I tried it myself, I ended up with the same error you're getting. Drawing on this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473880/how-to-apply-kineticjs-filter), it looks like an alternative is to set the filter via the config object of the Kinetic image:

```
    var myImg = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      filter: Kinetic.Filters.Contrast
    });
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R4ZDQ/3/) (the error is to do with attempting to apply your filter to an image from another domain and can, I think, be discounted).

Comment: Technically, your solution is ok, but I have a lot of dynamically added objects on my canvas. So it is quite hard to implement and I think in my case the performance will be not good enought (but I didn't do any tests). My temporary solution: just put the function into kineticJS file. Not perfect, but it works.